# SlideDown goes fast with Span vs Div

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```html
<span id="readMoreAmhausLink"><a style="color: #213d92" class="textlink" id="readMoreAmhaus"href="#"> ...Read More</a></span>
<span id = "bioAmhaus">text text text text text text text.<a style="color: #213d92" class="textlink" id="bioAmhausClose" href="#"> Close &uarr; </a></span>
```

```js
$('#bioAmhaus').hide();

$('#readMoreAmhaus').click(function (e) {             
    $('#bioAmhaus').slideDown(1000);
    $('#readMoreAmhausLink').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#bioAmhausClose').click(function (e) {
    $('#bioAmhaus').slideUp(1000);
    $('#readMoreAmhausLink').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem that I am having for the bioAmhaus span when I it does a slideDown it is fast. But when I do a slideUp it is slow.
I like to slideDown to be slow as well.

If I change it to the following I get a slow slideDown and slideUp but with the div the text goes to the next line. I like the text
to stay on the same line as how the span did.

```html
<span id="readMoreAmhausLink"><a style="color: #213d92" class="textlink" id="readMoreAmhaus"href="#"> ...Read More</a></span>
<div id = "bioAmhaus">text text text text text text text.<a style="color: #213d92"    class="textlink" id="bioAmhausClose" href="#"> Close &uarr; </a></div>
```

Comment: Your code looks OK - can you setup a jsfiddle demonstrating the behavior?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `.slideUP` and `.slideDown` to 2000 to make slide down slow as well as slide up.

```
$('#bioAmhaus').hide();

$('#readMoreAmhaus').click(function (e) {             
    $('#bioAmhaus').slideDown(2000);
    $('#readMoreAmhausLink').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#bioAmhausClose').click(function (e) {
    $('#bioAmhaus').slideUp(2000);
    $('#readMoreAmhausLink').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```